# Can't access some websites on Mac, but can access on iPad. Same network

Tags: dns, proxy, ping

When I try to access some of my sites (e.g. http://mono.company) I get a connection timeout. This only happens when I try to access sites that are on a certain server.

On the same WiFi network, when I try to do the same on Safari my iPad, it works just fine.

The specific error I get (in Chrome) is:

> This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Here is a screenshot of the error.

[image: 2]

- I can ping the domains just fine using `ping` in the terminal
- This happens in any browser e.g. in a clean Chrome Canary without plugins the same issue occurs
- My hosts file looks fine ( https://gist.github.com/Wolfr/8e95198053a96f84cd79 )
- I have tried with and without Google DNS (both ipv4 and ipv6)
- The same problem occurs on a clean new user account
- I have proxy set to autodiscovery (Mac OS default)
- I don't have any VPN configured
- My IP is the same on both devices

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "My IP is the same on both devices": **Don't do this**. Having the same IP address on multiple devices can cause many different issues.

Comment: Can you do a [`nslookup`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nslookup.1.html)?

Comment: @DavidPostill I took that to mean the external facing IP

Comment: @burgi. Hmm. I took it to mean local IP Address. Perhaps the OP will clarify.

Comment: It is by no means obvious that you are using the same set of DNSes. What you should do is to find out which DNSes you are using on the tablet, and use them also on the MAC: Does this solve your problem?

Comment: About the IP, it's just the ip of the router, which is the same for both devices since I am on the same network.

NSlookup is https://gist.github.com/Wolfr/a69b120eecd750127ca8 on laptop but I have no idea how to do that on an iPad.

I am not using the same set of DNSes (I use Google DNS on the Mac, and on the iPad it is vanilla), but if I change it to vanilla on the Mac it doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you cleared your DNS cache? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202516

Comment: Yes, I have tried clearing it, to no avail. The problem persists.